# SQL Server: Performance Analysis based on Wait Events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a performance analysis tool (for SQL Server 2005) that is based on Wait Events. My target is to bring “Average Wait Time” under 500ms.

Can you please suggest some good free tools for SQL Server 2005 performance analysis based on Wait Events?

Comment: [SQL Nexus](http://sqlnexus.codeplex.com/) could help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) is a methodology (hence a free tool) that handles exactly this situation.